# Mockito Get NPE when using argThat with custom ArgumentMatcher

Tags: mockito

I tried to use a custom ArgumentMatcher, but I always get NPE, and for me it's hard to find the reason now, even though I found the NPE related in the documentation.

```java
    @Test
    void debug() {

        class ListGetMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<Integer> {
            public boolean matches(Integer index) {
                return index == 2;
            }

        }

        List mock = mock(List.class);

        when(mock.get(argThat(new ListGetMatcher()))).thenReturn(200);

        assertEquals(200, mock.get(2));

        //when(mock.addAll(argThat(new ListOfTwoElements()))).thenReturn(true);

        //mock.addAll(Arrays.asList("one", "two"));

        //verify(mock).addAll(argThat(new ListOfTwoElements()));

    }
```

---

I  just change to use intThat and it's works fine.

```java
doReturn(200).when(mock).get(intThat(new ListGetMatcher()));
```

But the following case will still cause the NPE.

```java
when(substationQueryExecutor.getSubById(argThat(argument -> argument.getId() == 1L))).thenReturn(new Substation());
```

I expect a Substation to be returned when the id of argument is 999.  What should I do?

---

Here's the more detailed code, I'm stub for getSubById(), which has a SubstationQueryCmd parameter type, and I'm expecting a different value to be returned depending on the value of the SubstationQueryCmd's id. When I debugged the code, I found that the callback to matches() always passed me a null instead of the SubstationQueryCmd object. I don't understand what the problem is, maybe you know.

```java
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
class SubPowerSaveExecutorTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SubPowerSaveExecutor executor;

    @Mock
    private SubstationQueryExecutor queryExecutor;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    static class SubstationQueryArgMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<SubstationQueryCmd> {

        private final Long id;

        public SubstationQueryArgMatcher(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(SubstationQueryCmd argument) {
            // I debugged the code and found that the argument is null every time, I think this is the problem
            return argument.getId().longValue() == id;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void test() {

        when(queryExecutor.getSubById(argThat(new SubstationQueryArgMatcher(1L)))).thenReturn(new Substation());
        when(queryExecutor.getSubById(argThat(new SubstationQueryArgMatcher(999L)))).thenReturn(null);

        List<SubPowerDto> datas = new ArrayList<>();
        datas.add(new SubPowerDto().setMeterNum("meter01").setProviderName("diehl").setDate("2022-04-24 10:10:00").setSubstationId(1L).setPower(1D));
        datas.add(new SubPowerDto().setMeterNum("meter01").setProviderName("diehl").setDate("2022-04-24 10:20:00").setSubstationId(1L).setPower(1D));
        datas.add(new SubPowerDto().setMeterNum("meter01").setProviderName("diehl").setDate("2022-04-24 10:30:00").setSubstationId(1L).setPower(1D));

        datas.add(new SubPowerDto().setMeterNum("meter01").setProviderName("diehl").setDate("2022-04-24 10:30:00").setSubstationId(999L).setPower(1D));
        // getSubById() will be called in filterData
        List<SubPower> subPowers = executor.filterData(datas);
        assertEquals(1, subPowers.size());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `argThat`. As the source:

```
    public static <T> T argThat(Matcher<T> matcher) {
        return reportMatcher(matcher).<T>returnNull();
    }
```

To fix this, just change to use `intThat`.

```
    public static int intThat(Matcher<Integer> matcher) {
        return reportMatcher(matcher).returnZero();
    }
```

---

Your second problem: You may misunderstand the usages of `ArgumentMatcher`.

Your method `queryExecutor.getSubById` has param as a `Long`, but you use:

```
ArgumentMatcher<SubstationQueryCmd>
```

This is incorrect. Change it to:

```
ArgumentMatcher<Long>
```

Then you can use `longThat` instead of `argThat`.

---

In case of `substationQueryExecutor.getSubById` has param as a `SubstationQueryCmd`.

Then you just need to check `null` in your custom matcher:

```
        @Override
        public boolean matches(SubstationQueryCmd argument) {
            if (argument == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return argument.getId().longValue() == id;
        }
```

Because: that is an object, and it's possible to be `null`. So that happens at the line you are trying to stub. So you will need to check `null` in your custom argument matcher if you use this syntax:

```
when(...).thenReturn(...)
```

To avoid changing your custom argument matcher, you can change to use this syntax instead:

```
doReturn(...).when(yourMock).doSomething()
```

So your code should be:

```
        doReturn(new Substation()).when(queryExecutor).getSubById(argThat(new SubstationQueryArgMatcher(1L)));
        doReturn(null).when(queryExecutor).getSubById(argThat(new SubstationQueryArgMatcher(999L)));
```

Happy coding!

Comment: thanks, in this case it's works.
But I still want to use argThat for some argument. like that :
```java
        when(substationQueryExecutor.getSubById(argThat(command -> command.getId() == 999))).thenReturn(new Substation());
```
In the above case, I also got NPE.

Comment: Base one which type of argument, you have more than just `argThat` to use. You may want to read more docs about these argumentMatcher.

Comment: Example: your `mock.get(index)` - the `index` is `int`, not `Integer`, so it could be `null`.

Comment: If you use your own class, then you can use `argThat`, but if you are using something like `int`, `boolean`, `byte` ... then you have `intThat`, booleanThat`, byteThat`, etc...

Comment: In your case: `java         when(substationQueryExecutor.getSubById(argThat(command -> command.getId() == 999))).thenReturn(new Substation());` - I don't know anything about your method, so I can't give any advise here. I'm pretty sure you can do in any cases if you read and understand fully the api and docs.

Comment: Thanks bro, I've updated the description, would be great If you could just take another look.

Comment: You may misunderstand the usages of `ArgumentMatchers`. Your method `queryExecutor.getSubById` has param as a `Long`, but you use `ArgumentMatcher<SubstationQueryCmd>` which is incorrect. I'll edit my answer for this

Comment: Not really bro. I am sorry that my method name misled you, its parameters are indeed SubstationQueryCmd,  Only SubstationQueryCmd has one field, which is the id

Comment: Added for your case if you have `SubstationQueryCmd` as param.

Comment: Also, remember to rename your method to `getSubByCmd`  :) It will make more sense.

Comment: Please see my edited answer to include this case.

Comment: Thank you for your patience,  Just now I solved the problem, I just replaced the annotation Mock with MockBean, and replaced the annotation InjectMock with Autowired. 
Thanks again and nice day